# how the web-service can display the contents of object of type array

Tags: python, json, web-services, flask, flask-restful

in the below posted code, `featuresArray` is an array of features.i would like the below posted webservice to return the 'featuresArray' as stated in the code. when run the App i receive

```
internal server error
```

however, when i return for example

```
feature[0] or specify the index
```

the webservice displays the value.

so how can i let the web-service return and display the object `freaturesArray`

**python code**:

```
@app.route("/geodata/<string:polygonCoordinates>", methods=['GET'] )
def geodata(polygonCoordinates):
...
...
url = url.replace(" ","%20")
backendResponseAsJSON = readResponseAsJSONForURL(url)
geojsonObjectAsJSON = loadDataAsJSON(backendResponseAsJSON['geojson'][0])
featuresArray = geojsonObjectAsJSON['features']
for feature in featuresArray:
    pass#print (feature)

#baseURL = config['EndPoint']['https'] + config['EndPoint']['url'] + config['EndPoint']['api_key'] + config['EndPoint']['start'] + polygonCoordinates + "," + polygonCoordinates + config['EndPoint']['end'] + polygonCoordinates + "," + polygonCoordinates
#print("baseURL: %s"%(baseURL))
return featuresArray
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the array or the list must be enclosed inside
str()
just do as follows:

```
 return str(featureArray)
```